# Not working data-disabled-days in datedropper

Tags: jquery, datepicker, datedropper

We are using **[DateDropper](http://felicegattuso.com/projects/datedropper/)** and disabled particular date but not disabled. Using html attributes following, but not working as expected:

```
<input type="text" id="booking-date" data-lang="en" data-large-mode="true" data-large-default="true" data-min-year="2017" data-max-year="2080" data-disabled-days="05/06/2018">
```

Comment: Which `datepicker` plugin?

Comment: Hi pedram ,
Datedropper plugin
http://felicegattuso.com/projects/datedropper/

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to this [topic](https://github.com/felicegattuso/Datedropper3/issues/63) it seems this plugin has a bug on this future, but I provide a dirty trick/solution for you, but for now there is no native solution to fix this issue.

```js
$('input').dateDropper();

$('input').on('change input', function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  
  var disabledDays = $(this).attr("data-disabled-days").split(",");
  if ($.inArray(val, disabledDays) !== -1) {
    $(this).val("");
    alert("Sorry this date not allowed!");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datedropper/2.0/datedropper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datedropper/2.0/datedropper.min.css" />
<input type="text" id="booking-date" data-lang="en" data-large-mode="true" data-large-default="true" data-min-year="2017" data-max-year="2080" data-disabled-days="05/06/2018">
```